# Can I load images from a folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I got the snippet online:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dir = "";
    var fileextension = ".jpg";
    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function ()
            {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
                $("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));
            });
        }
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

But when I try to run this nothing happens. The images are in the same folder (on my Desktop) where the .html file. But can I do this with javascript, or do I need some backend like PHP/ASP.NET or something?

Comment: Since there is  $.ajax you definitely need backend [Lear more about ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: There is no feature in HTML5 that lets me load files from a folder and filter by extension?

Comment: You'd need to get a list of files from somewhere. As an alternative, you could generate the <img> tags in advance.